# get data from csv by columnname with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a csv file with 160 columns and several lines of row data (1st column names, 2nd and further data). Columns are seperated by a ; and rows by ,

When opening the file in Excel is it formatted like this for example:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12
```

I want to read the CSV file in C# and **use LINQ as much as possible**.

**(edit)**
How do I get the row values as string[] for the row that has in column "E" the value 5 for example ? This should return the string[] values of the 2nd row.

I am using C# 4.0 in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

you can query a spreadsheet as a "classic" datasource like Sql Server. Create a connection string pointing to the path of your file and use the Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider (it is not available on x64 os, in that case you will have to use third party component to establish the connection). Once this is done you can run sql statements over you're .xls . 
You cannot run queries using LINQ directly on the xls like you normally do using LINQ to SQL (the datacontext can be created only over sql server). 
To access the value of a column on a row, after the query,you have to iterate over the returned datareader:

```
using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string result = dr["E"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Here you can find some useful infos : http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension function like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> RowValuesFromColumnID<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source, T columnID) {
        var index = source.First().Select((x,i) => new { x, i }).Where(x => x.x.Equals(columnID)).FirstOrDefault().i;
        return source.Skip(1).SelectMany(x => x.Where((y,i) => i == index));
    }
```

And then get the string array like so:

```
    //read in file
    var csv = "A;B;C;D;E;F,1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9;10;11;12";

    csv.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split(';')).RowValuesFromColumnID("E").ToArray();
```

Which will return

```
5
11
```

**NOTE:**  The extension function above provides **no error handling whatsoever** and anticipates **perfect input** (it expects the first IEnumerable to be the column names).  You probably want to add some null checks in there (among other things), but hopefully this will get you started.

Please let me know if I misunderstood anything about the question or if there are any problems!